# Pandas: Filter grouped Series by count of occurencies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, which I use `groupby` on for further data aggregation:

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data={"id": [1,2,2,3,3], "review_id": [1,2,3,4,5], "text": ["good", "bad", "nice", "awesome", "dont buy"]})
grouped_df = test_df.groupby(by=["id", "review_id"]).apply(lambda x: [x["text"]])
```

Which give me the following series:

```
    id  review_id
1   1                [[good]]
2   2                 [[bad]]
    3                [[nice]]
3   4             [[awesome]]
    5            [[dont buy]]
dtype: object
```

Now I need a way, how I can further reduce this series, as I only want ids with more than 1 review. so I want the *id 1* to be dropped.
I just dont know how I could use `aggregate()` or `apply()` for this task.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `transform`

```
out = grouped_df[grouped_df.groupby(level=0).transform('size')>1]
id  review_id
2   2                 [[bad]]
    3                [[nice]]
3   4             [[awesome]]
    5            [[dont buy]]
dtype: object
```

Or let us do `duplicated`

```
out = grouped_df[grouped_df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)]
id  review_id
2   2                 [[bad]]
    3                [[nice]]
3   4             [[awesome]]
    5            [[dont buy]]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you passing `level=0` ?

Comment: @MichaelJanzM level 0  is  your id here, we would like check how many id repeat ~ , that is why I pass level =0